# Neovim(vim), resizes my splits after closing Nerdtree

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, vim, nvim

I have some issue. I opened some files in vertical split, and resized it to work with it more comfortable. But when I'm opening and closing nerdtree, all my panes resized by default.
Here is I'm resized my panes
[image]

Open NEDRTree
[image]

And after closing, all my panes goes to standard size
[image]

After that, I do evrytime to resize it to my comfortable size. Do anybody knows how to fix it?

```
NVIM v0.4.3
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
```

Answer (score 1):

This command in `.vimrc` helps me: `set noequalalways`